# eclispe : An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, stack-overflow

Does anyone face the following exception in eclipse when project is updated for maven using Right-click on project -> Maven -> Update Project.

Dialog 1 =>  **An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project"**

Dialog 2 =>  **A stack overflow error has occured . YOu are recommened to exit the workbench. ...Do you want to exit the workbench?**

Reported the same for eclipse bug team : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=443050

Eclipse version : 4.3

==================================ECLIPSE LOGS ==================================

```
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
!STACK 0
```

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.containsAll(AbstractCollection.java:278)
    at java.util.AbstractSet.equals(AbstractSet.java:78)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.graph.transformer.NearestVersionConflictResolver$1.accept(NearestVersionConflictResolver.java:193)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.graph.PathRecordingDependencyVisitor.visitEnter(PathRecordingDependencyVisitor.java:88)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.GraphEdge.accept(GraphEdge.java:198)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.GraphEdge.accept(GraphEdge.java:202)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.GraphEdge.accept(GraphEdge.java:202)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.GraphEdge.accept(GraphEdge.java:202)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.GraphEdge.accept(GraphEdge.java:202)
   .....
```

Comment: check your pom, you may be having modules added to each other as dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest Maven (3.2.3) from http://maven.apache.org/ and run it from the command line. It should give you a useful error message instead of a stack overflow.

Background: There was a bug in some versions of Maven which couldn't detect cycles in the dependencies.