# SpringToolSuite4 - An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project"

Tags: spring-boot, maven

Whenever I try to build/run my project in SpringToolSuite4, I get below error -

```
An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
    loader constraint violation: 
    loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @a0e620d wants to load class
    org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject. 
    A different class with the same name was previously loaded by 
    org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @1d95501b. 
    (org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject is in unnamed module of loader 
    org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @1d95501b, parent loader 'platform')
```

I'm not able to understand what can be the issue.

I tried -

- Deleting plugins
- Restarting STS4
- Restarting STS4, restarting with `-clean` flag

I even looked into below -

[eclispe : An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project" java.lang.StackOverflowError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617201/eclispe-an-internal-error-occurred-during-updating-maven-project-java-lang)

[Maven error :"Updating Maven Project"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401684/maven-error-updating-maven-project)

Comment: Does your build work on plain command line?

Comment: Yes that works. Only problem within my STS.

Comment: `org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject is in unnamed module of loader` which JDK you are using for Eclipse STS?